# Debian - Create new partition with fdisk and set size ( Last sector )

Tags: debian, partition, fdisk, size

please could someone help me with my problem of create new disk partition in Debian ?

I'am using Proxmox where I have created a few virtual machines.

On one of virtual machines where have installed Linux - Debian I have problem with enough free disk space.

So I decied that I created new partion on disk just for backup files.

**Step 1.**

I resized disk in Proxmox from 100GB to 250GB

**Step 2.**

I logged in to the Debian where I would want to create new partition for storage  backup files . Partition shoud have 70GB

**Step 3.**

I run fdisk to create new partition + I'am attaching screenshot (create-new-partion-fdisk.jpg ) where I mark up few command and option that I select, but I have problem that I can't set size of partition to 70GB (+70G). I when i try it set value "+70G" for "Last Selector" question I get Error "Value out of range"

[image]

---

Please could you help me how I can achieve this the most easy way ? I don't have such experience with Debian so if some kind soul would help me I would be glad for that !  Specific commands would be extremely halpful

Thank you !

Comment: 1.  [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.   I know you're trying to be helpful with all that fancy red highlighting, but that kind of thing **really** doesn't help.  2. why did you make an Extended partition (vda2) that only holds a ~1GB swap partition (vda5)?  I'd run `swapoff` then delete both the swap and extended partition, then create new primary partitions.

Comment: and edit /etc/fstab to suit the new partition layout, of course.   BTW, rather than resizing vda, you may have been better off just adding a new virtual disk (vdb) with at least 70 GB.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See the blue mark.

There is some gap between vda1 and vda2.

So fdisk will create partition between vda1 and vda2 by default. That's not what we want.

To solve it, you should tell fdisk to create partition after vda2.

When fdisk prompt for First sector

You should type 209713152 (last sector of vda2  +1)